# Combining two setup in one file with pip install

Tags: pip, pytorch

I have the problem that when I use `from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension` it is using the  precxx11-abi which is not compatible with the libraries I am linking against.
I  have reached to a point now where I can split up the cuda code and making it independent on the libA.so library, while the other part is built using from `pybind11.setup_helpers import  build_ext`

```
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension
from setuptools import setup
import os

os.environ['CC'] = 'g++'

def make_cuda_ext(name, module, path, sources):
    cuda_ext = CUDAExtension(
        name='%s.%s' % (module, name),
        sources=[os.path.join(path, src) for src in sources]
    )
    return cuda_ext


ext_modules = [
        Pybind11Extension("main_pybind", ["src/cpp/pybind/main.cpp"],
                          libraries=['libA'],
                          extra_compile_args=['-std=c++20'],
                          language='c++'),
    ]

ext_modules1 = [
    make_cuda_ext(
        name='nnnms',
        module='nnnms.libb',
        path='third-party/nnnms/src/nnnms',
        sources=[
            'nnnms_cpu.cpp',
            'nnnms_kernel.cu',
        ]
    )
]

setup(ext_modules=ext_modules1, cmdclass={"build_ext": BuildExtension})
setup(ext_modules=ext_modules, cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext})
```

however, when adding the two setup I get following error:

```
  error: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/main_pybind.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory
  [end of output]
```